# Why HMS Push Kit Via Coding Assistant shows error code : 80200003:error message : Oauth Token expired

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

While implementing Push kit through HMS Coding Assistant I'am gettingthe given error
error code : 80200003, error message : Oauth Token expired
How to solve the issue

Comment: Can you please specify the version of the HMS Core Toolkit you are using? Also, at which point did you get the error?

Comment: Could you please provide the procedure for reproducing the problem? This message indicates that the token used by the Push Kit has expired. Normally [the tool](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/overview-0000001050060881) automatically reapplies for a new token. If the tool fails to reapply for it, the failure cause is also displayed. If the fault persists, please restart the system. Besides, in the latest version 3.0.2.300, the tool automatically applies for a new token each time it is used. Therefore, the token will not expire.

Comment: I'm using HMS Core ToolKit version 3.0.1.300. I will update and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason**

Error code 80200003 means that the token used by the Push Kit has expired. Normally the tool automatically reapplies for a new token. If the tool fails to reapply for it, the failure cause is also displayed.

**Solution**

If the fault persists, please restart the system. Besides, in the latest version 3.0.2.300, the tool automatically applies for a new token each time it is used. Therefore, the token will not expire.

You can use the auxiliary tools provided by Coding Assistant: Message Test and Error Codes, to automatically fill in the app token.

Message Test is a tool used to test the Push Kit's function of pushing messages from the server to phones.
Error Codes: error codes and handling suggestions provided by Push Kit. Before debugging, ensure that **Auto Analysis** is enabled.

The process is as follows:

Parameter: Please Input your token

Setting: This parameter is automatically set when an app is running on a device.

1. To automatically fill in the app token, manually enable the log analysis function and run the app again.
2. If the log analysis function is not enabled, use either of the following ways:

a. When you run the app, the Event Log window prompts you whether to enable the log analysis function. Click **Turn On**.

b. Click **Error Codes** and turn on Auto Analysis in the upper right corner.

For more information, see [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/coding-assistant-0000001050061057).